# OpenCV sending image over HTTP with base64 on iOS with C++

Tags: c++, ios, post, opencv, base64

I am creating an application on the iOS where I send a list of keyPoints (this works) and a `Mat` image generated from the `OrbDescriptorExtractor`. The sending of the image works, the base64 received is the same as the base64 send. So my guess is that it goes wrong on the encoding and decoding.

The image on the left is before the encoding and the image on the right is the decoded image which is received on the server:

[image: Before base64]
[image: After base64]

This is the code that encodes the `Mat`(desc) image with base64, the base64 function I used is from [this site](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html).

```
char sendFile[1000];
char temp[100];

std::sprintf(temp, "^^%d^^%d^^", desc.cols, desc.rows);
strcat(sendFile, temp);

const unsigned char* inBuffer = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(desc.data);

strcat(sendFile, base64_encode(inBuffer, strlen((char*)inBuffer)).c_str());
strcat(sendFile, "\0");
```

After this the file gets saved with a HTTP Post on a server and then a C++ script is opened with `exec()` in PHP, this works.

After this the image is decoded this way:

```
int processData(string input, int* width, int* height){
    int cur = 0, k = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        if(input.substr(i, 2) == "^^"){
            if(cur == 0){
                k = i + 2;          
            }else if(cur == 1){
                *width = getIntFromString(input, k, i);         
                k = i + 2;
            }else{
                *height = getIntFromString(input, k, i);        
                break;
            }
            cur++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int error, w, h;
string line, data;
ifstream file;

file.open(argv[1]);

if(file.is_open()){
    error = processData(line, &w, &h);
    if(error != 0){
        printf("Processing keypoints failed \n");
        return 1;
    } 
    getline(file, line);
    data = base64_decode(line);

    file.close();
}else{
    printf("Couldn't open file.\n");
    return 1;
}

Mat tex_des(Size(w, h), CV_8UC1, (void*)data.c_str());
```

How can I send an OpenCV image the correct way without losing data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you MUST NOT use any str... functions on binary data!!

strlen((char*)inBuffer) is stopping at the 1st zero, giving a wrong result

use desc.total() instead for the buffer length

Comment: Thank you very much this worked! Could you explain why I can't use str functions on binary data?

Comment: strlen walks the array, until it finds the 1st 0. which is fine for strings, but stupid for binary information, like an image, where a 0 is a total legit black pixel. look at your image, it has lots of those.   strcat, strcpy, whatever they all suffer from this same problem

Answer (score 0):

I am using a slightly different approach. I will write it, Hope it will help:

```
//Consider we have the image saved in UIImage
UIImage * myImage;

//Get the data 
NSData imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0);

//I am using this extension to encode to base 64 (https://gist.github.com/Abizern/1643491)
//Article from the save author http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html
NSString *encodedImage = [imageData base64EncodedString];
```

and I send `encodedImage` to the server.

Comment: But when it's converted to a JPEG it's compressed. and because it is used on a calculation function I fear that it will result in errors.